# Tkinter: Placing the Labels one after another in Canvas relatively.

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I would like to arrange the Labels in the canvas one after another. But placement is not coming out as desired.

Below is the function that inserts the labels in the canvas. But the ones in the for loop overlaps. Reason - some labels are larger in size than the other. Hence, I assume that largest size be 80 and do the placements respectively. I would like to change this type of approach. Rather I want the labels to be placed relatively one after the other.

```
def calculate(*args):
try:
    ttk.Label(canvas, text="Result:").place(x=20, y=20)
    ttk.Label(canvas, text="Topic:").place(x=20, y=80)
    ttk.Label(canvas, textvariable=topic).place(x=200, y=80)
    ttk.Label(canvas, text="Environment:").place(x=20, y=120)
    ttk.Label(canvas, textvariable=environment).place(x=200, y=120)
    ttk.Label(canvas, text="Event Results:").place(x=20, y=160)

    inputValue=TextArea.get("1.0","end-1c")

    len_max=0
    result={}
    for s in inputValue.splitlines():
        data = MainInstance.searchWithPayload(s)            
        result[s]=data
        if len(s+data) > len_max:
            len_max = len(s+data)

    i = 190
    for key in result.keys():
        print(key)
        print(result[key])
        ttk.Label(canvas, text=key+"\n\n"+result[key], wraplength=800).place(x=20,y = i)
        i = i + 80

except ValueError:
    pass
```

Below is the code that integrates the canvas widget. And the calculate button calls the calculate function.

```
ttk.Button(page2, text="Exit",command=page1.quit).grid(column=2, row=8)
ttk.Button(page2, text="Calculate", command=calculate).grid(column=3, row=8)

canvas = Canvas(root, width=900, height=universal_height)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)


root.mainloop()
```

**Actually, there are two parts of the question:**

1. How can I relatively place the label to stop the overlapping?
2. I tried adding the scroll to the canvas. But the application does not respond and does not pop up.

Code for adding the scrollbar:

```
canvas=Canvas(root,bg='#FFFFFF',width=300,height=300,scrollregion=
(0,0,500,500))
hbar=Scrollbar(root,orient=HORIZONTAL)
hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
hbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
vbar=Scrollbar(root,orient=VERTICAL)
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(width=300,height=300)
canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
```

This is the output that I am getting, wherein the first two labels are getting overlapped.
[image: output - overlapped labels]

Comment: Why are you using `place`? `pack` (and to a lesser extent, `grid`) are designed to easily make widgets appear in rows and/or columns.

Comment: With grid, the size of the canvas window reduces to the size of its contents.
To fix the frame size I thought of using place.

Comment: It seems to me that `.grid()` would be far better for you here. Is it entirely necessary to put all of your content in to a `canvas`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scroll the widgets that you put inside the canvas, you need to use `canvas.create_window(x, y, window=label)` instead of `label.place(...)`.

I suggest you to create a frame, grid all you labels inside it so that you won't have overlapping issues and put the frame inside the canvas using `create_window` to be able to scroll it:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def on_resize(event):
    """Resize canvas scrollregion when the canvas is resized."""
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('100x100')

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)

frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)
# create and grid the labels
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        ttk.Label(frame, text="Label %i-%i" % (i, j)).grid(row=i, column=j, padx=10, pady=10)
# put the frame in the canvas
canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor='nw', window=frame)
# add the scrollbars
vbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical', command=canvas.yview)
hbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient='horizontal', command=canvas.xview)
canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=hbar.set,
                 yscrollcommand=vbar.set,
                 scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='eswn')
vbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
hbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')

canvas.bind('<Configure>', on_resize)

root.mainloop()
```